# How to use dx list in DevExtreme

Tags: angular, devextreme

How to write correctly using dx-list?

I have an array

```
fields: Array<{field: string, direction: boolean}>
```

I'm writing like this

```
dx-list([items]="fields",
        selectionMode="single")
```

At the output I get a sheet, but I can not get the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a complete [sample here](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/List/ListWithSearchBar/Angular/Light/)

```
<dx-list 
        #list
        [dataSource]="products">
            <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'item'">
                <div>{{data.field}}</div>
            </div>
    </dx-list>
```